# How to run an action on every route transition in ember?

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember application with several routes and I want to scroll the page to top every time the user makes a transition. The problem is that I don't want to duplicate the same code on every route's `didTransition`method.

So, Is there a way that I can observe all routes transitions and execute (declare) an action in just one place ?

Another way to put put this: If I have a parent route, can I fire the same action to all of its children ?

My current solution is to fire the action on every route's `didTransition` method like this:

```
//router.js
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('login');
   this.route('portal',{ path:'/'}, function() {
      this.route('clientes');
      this.route('convite');
      this.route('usuario', function() {
      this.route('view', { path: '/:id' });
  });
 });

 //everyChildren.route.js
 didTransition(){
   this.super(...arguments);
   Ember.$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
 }
```

Is there a way to do this ?

PS:. I am using Ember version 2.14.0

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [ember-router-scroll](https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/ember-router-scroll)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to define [didTransition](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.2/classes/Route/events/didTransition?anchor=didTransition) action on `application` route. If child route does not define handler for event, it should bubble up to parent route and `application` is a most top route.

Alternatively, you can create a [mixin](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.2/classes/Mixin) with `didTransition` action, and add that mixin to certain routes.

Also, looking at your code I think you might be interested in using [liquid-fire](https://github.com/ember-animation/liquid-fire) addon (if your goal is animated transitions)

Comment: I found out that ember's default behavior is to preserve scroll state on transition and I am trying your mixin solution. I also found this useful like https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/resetting_scroll_on_route_changes/. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ember-router-scroll`](https://github.com/dollarshaveclub/ember-router-scroll).

This addon does what you want